# Easy way to spot isolated essential singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

The way I was taught about *isolated essential singularities* was that the Laurent series of the function about the point in question has infinitely many $1/z^{\alpha}$ terms where $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$. For instance, the function $f(z)=\exp(1/z)$ has an expansion, about $0$, given by
$$\exp(1/z)= 1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{6z^3}+\dots$$
My question is, is there any easier way to spot isolated essential singularities? I'll admit, the function in question is easy, since the Taylor series expansion of $f(z)=e^z$ is very familiar, but is there a better way, in general, of finding isolated essential singularities without necessarily considering the series expansion?

Comment: You can ask them to go play outside. Isolated singularities usually don't like doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is an entire function that is not a polynomial, then $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Hence, if $f$ is entire (and not a polynomial), and $g$ has a *pole* at $z=a$, then $f(g(z))$ has an essential singularity at $z=a$. In practice this covers most cases you are likely to encounter in a first course in complex analysis.

Comment: Concise and perfect answer. Thank you.